# Como trabalhar com o @Html.DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Amigos
Após seguir o exemplo fiz o ajuste no código, não estou conseguindo enviar a informação para a ActionResult

```html
@model ProjetoDelphiMobile.Models.cliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = ""; 
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

    function BuscarCaminho()
    {
        var srcRecebe = document.getElementById("selecao").innerText;
        alert(srcRecebe);

        if (srcRecebe > 0) {

            $.post("/ConsultaCliente/AtualizaFoto", { caminhofoto: srcRecebe }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data)
                window.location.reload();
            })
        }

    }

</script>

               

<form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">


           <label>Foto:</label>
           <div id="selecao" onchange="BuscarCaminho()" >
                 @Html.DropDownList("idFoto", String.Empty) 
           </div>


           <div >
@*     <div >
         <img id="foto" src="@Url.Action("AtualizaFoto", "ConsultaCliente", new {caminhofoto = "caminho" })" alt="thumbnail" />
       </div>*@


           <br />
    
           <label>Nome:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nome, new { disabled = false })

           <label>Nome:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nome, new { disabled = false })
           
            <label>Nome do pai:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pai, new { disabled = false })

            <label>Nome da Mãe:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mae, new { disabled = false })

            <label>Data de Nascimento:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.datanascimento, new { disabled = false })



        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="e">
            <li><a href="/ConsultaCliente">Retornar para consulta</a></li>
        </ul>

    </fieldset>




</form>
```

Na minha Views:

```
        public ActionResult AtualizaFoto(string caminhofoto)
    {
        int largura = 100;
        int altura  = 100;
        WebImage webImagem = new WebImage(@caminhofoto).Resize(largura, altura, false, false);
        return File(webImagem.GetBytes(), @caminhofoto);
    }
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar jQuery pra fazer isso? Você pôs a tag na pergunta mas não está usando. Por que?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, eu coloquei a Tag porque estou usando JQuery, agora se você diz que é mais fácil então me mostra como você faria para resolver esta situação?

Comment: Tranquilo. Em qual campo fica a informação de caminho?

Comment: ViewBag.idFoto = new SelectList(dao.fotos, "idFoto", "Foto");
O idFoto recebe o caminho que é visualizado dentro do DropDownList

Answer (score 2):

Em jQuery, sua função ficaria assim:

```
<script >

        function BuscarCaminho()
        {
            //Pega o elemento 'select'
            var select = $("#idFoto");
            //Altera o valor do atributo 'src' da imagem para carregar a imagem selecionada
            if (select.length > 0) {
                $('#caminho').attr("src", select.val());
                alert(select.val());
            }
        }

</script>
```

---

Há mais alguns ajustes que serão necessários. No `Controller`, por exemplo, devolva um FileResult ao invés de um ActionResult:

```
public FileResult AtualizaFoto(string caminhofoto)
{
    int largura = 100;
    int altura  = 100;
    var webImagem = new WebImage(@caminhofoto).Resize(largura, altura, false, false);
    return File(webImagem.GetBytes(), @caminhofoto);
}
```

Outra coisa é este callback, que do jeito que está não vai funcionar. O certo seria algo como:

```
$.post("/ConsultaCliente/AtualizaFoto", { caminhofoto: srcRecebe }).done(function (data) {
    $('#caminho').attr("src", data);
})
```

Comment: fiz os ajustes baseado com seu exemplo,
Você poderia me ajudar a descobri o porque não estou conseguindo enviar a informação para a ActionResult, quero retornar  imagem. agradeço

Comment: Adicionei o código completo na minha pergunta.

Comment: @itasouza Modifiquei a resposta.

Comment: Fiz a atualização da resposta. Agradeço a sua ajuda.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59059/como-chamar-a-mesma-actionresult-mais-de-1-vez-para-atualiza-a-p%C3%A1gina