# Como chamar a mesma ActionResult mais de 1 vez para atualizar a página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso chamar a ActionResult cada vez que seleciono um registro novo no DropDownList chamando apenas 1 vez quando carrega a página.

No Controller

```
        private string PegarCaminhoImagem(Int16 controle)
    {
        sistema_mobileEntities dao = new sistema_mobileEntities();
        dao.fotos.Find(controle);
        var caminho = dao.fotos.First().Foto;
        return caminho;
    }


    public ActionResult AtualizaFoto(Int16 caminhofoto)
    {
        int largura = 100; 
        int altura = 100;
        String CaminhoFoto = "";

        try
        {

           CaminhoFoto = PegarCaminhoImagem(caminhofoto);

           var webImagem = new WebImage(@CaminhoFoto).Resize(largura, altura, false, false);
           return File(webImagem.GetBytes(), @CaminhoFoto);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("A Imagem não existe : " + ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Na Views:

```html
@model ProjetoDelphiMobile.Models.cliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = ""; 
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#idFoto").on("change", function () {

            var srcRecebe = $($(this)).val();

            if (srcRecebe > 0) {

                $.post("/ConsultaCliente/AtualizaFoto", { caminhofoto: srcRecebe }).done(function (data) {
                    $('#caminho').attr("src", data);
                })
            }
        });
    });

</script>

               

<form>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">


           <label>Foto:</label>
           <div id="selecao">
                 @Html.DropDownList("idFoto", String.Empty) 
           </div>


           <div >
             <img id="foto" src="@Url.Action("AtualizaFoto", "ConsultaCliente", new {caminhofoto = "caminho" })" alt="thumbnail" />
           </div>


           <br />
    
           <label>Nome:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nome, new { disabled = false })

           <label>Nome:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nome, new { disabled = false })
           
            <label>Nome do pai:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pai, new { disabled = false })

            <label>Nome da Mãe:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mae, new { disabled = false })

            <label>Data de Nascimento:</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.datanascimento, new { disabled = false })



        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="e">
            <li><a href="/ConsultaCliente">Retornar para consulta</a></li>
        </ul>

    </fieldset>




</form>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o seu problema? Não está conseguindo acessar a ActionResult? Não está conseguindo retornar os dados?

Comment: O problema é que está chamando apenas 1 vez quando carrega a página.

Comment: Quando você altera o Select, ele busca apenas 1 vez? Em uma nova tentativa não faz a busca na Action!?

Comment: Sim, só chama 1 vez, é quero chamar sempre que selecionar uma informação nova

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar seu código para pegar o valor do `Select` da seguinte forma:

Quando você usa o `HTML Helper` : `@Html.DropDownList("idFoto", String.Empty)` o parâmetro "idFoto" fica sendo o valor dos atributos `id` e `name` do `select` quando este e renderizado para HTML.

Usando o recurso `Inspecionar Elemento`do `Google Chrome` por exemplo, poderá perceber que o seu `@Html.DropDownList` quando renderizado vira: `<select id="idFoto" name="idFoto">`, o seu `select` no evento `change` continua retornando os mesmos valores.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#idFoto").on("change", function () {

        var srcRecebe = $($(this)).val();

        if (srcRecebe > 0) {

            $.post("/ConsultaCliente/AtualizaFoto", { caminhofoto: srcRecebe }).done(function (data) {
                $('#caminho').attr("src", data);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Fazendo isso, toda vez que o `Select` sofrer alteração será executado esse código, pode retirar também o `onchange="BuscarCaminho()"`, não vai ser mais necessário, visto que o código acima pega diretamente do `Select`.

Comment: Fiz alteração da perguntar com o seu código, como está pegando o idFoto, alterei o meu controller onde tenho uma função para me retornar o nome do caminho da imagem. Só que a imagem não esta carregando, o caminho da foto seria “C:\imagem.jpg”

Comment: @itasouza Acho que você confundiu as coisas, vou editar minha resposta.